# jQuery on hover opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have tried and failed to get this working. Basically I am trying to get it so that when you hover over one div, it should change the sibling's opacity to 0.5 that has `class="receiver"`.

If you see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/UzxPJ/1/), there are 2 divs with `class="outerwrapper"`, and both contain 2 divs of classes `hover` and `receiver`. When you hover over the div with class `hover`, the `receiver`'s opacity should be set to 0.5, but only the one inside the same div (outerwrapper).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *need* to use jQuery, or JavaScript, for this (though you *can*<sup>1</sup>), CSS is quite capable in most browsers of achieving the same end-result:

```
.hover:hover + .receiver {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UzxPJ/6/).

And also, even with 'only' CSS, in modern/compliant browsers, it's possible to use fade transitions (or, strictly speaking, to transition the opacity):

```
.receiver {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.hover:hover + .receiver {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UzxPJ/22/).

---

1. I was going to provide a JavaScript/jQuery solution as well, but there are several others already posted, now, and I'd rather not repeat other people's answers in my own (it just *feels* like plagiarism/copying).

Comment: Oh, I was just adding those in as you commented! =) And you're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! =D

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/UzxPJ/3/

```
$(function(){
    $(".hover").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).siblings(".receiver").css("opacity", 0.5);    
        },
        function(){
            $(this).siblings(".receiver").css("opacity", 1);  
        }        
    );            
});​
```

**References**

`.siblings()` - Get the siblings of an element - http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

`.hover()` - Catch the mouseover/mouseout events - http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Great answer +1, alltho I would suggest using ".fadeTo(0, 0.5); instead of .css(). edit: ooh and cache $(this), and using .on('hover', function) instead of .hover :)

Comment: @ninja you can't cache `$(this)` here - they're two separate callbacks.

Comment: @ninja Agreed, there are several ways to achieve the same thing. I thought this was the most descriptive though.

Comment: @ninja and `.on('hover', ...)` doesn't work if you need separate "in" and "out" functions.

Comment: @alnitak, it don't? havn't tried myself but .hover just points to the .on('hover'... in the jquery source doesn't it?

Comment: @ninja no, it doesn't, `.hover(a,b)` does `.mouseenter(a).mouseleave(b||a)`.  The `.on()` version only supports a single callback.

Comment: @Alnitak I guess you could pass the event to the callback in `.on()` and check it with an if-statement whether it was a mouse-enter or a mouse-out event that triggered, and then act accordingly? Haven't tried it, and it would have made a lousy messy example, but I guess it would be possible?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson yeah, that would work, but for this trivial example it's easier to have two callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.hover').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('.receiver').css('opacity', 0.5);
}, function() {
    $(this).next('.receiver').css('opacity', 1.0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2K8B2/

(use `.siblings` or `.nextAll` if the `.receiver` is not necessarily the next element)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').hover(function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parent('.outerwrapper');
        $parent.find('.receiver').css({ opacity : 0.5 });
    }, function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parent('.outerwrapper');
        $parent.find('.receiver').css({ opacity : 1 });
    });
});​
```

Comment: ... but is unnecessarily complicated.  Traversing siblings is very efficient in the DOM - there's no need to ascend to the parent node.

Comment: Ya this is the wrong solution. I've already voted the .siblings() a better solution.